# MATLAB several surface plots in 3D using matrix

Tags: matlab, plot

I would like to show several spheres in my 3D spaces, each with a different center location and radius. So I followed the tutorial by Matlab and I get the following result. The only problem is that I might have hundreds of spheres to plot so it won't be possible to write down hundreds of lines. Is there a way to use the surf() function with a matrix input? Maybe surf(x,y,z) with x,y and z matrix? Thanks!

```
hold on;
[x,y,z] = sphere;
r = 50;
s1 = surf(x*r,y*r,z*r,'FaceAlpha',0.1);
s2 = surf((x+3)*r,(y-2)*r,z*r,'FaceAlpha',0.1); % centered at (3,-2,0) 
s3 = surf(x*r,(y+1)*r,(z-3)*r,'FaceAlpha',0.1); % centered at (0,1,-3)

s1.EdgeColor = 'none';
s2.EdgeColor = 'none';
s3.EdgeColor = 'none';
```

[image]

Comment: `x`, `y` and `z` are already (2D) matrices. Why do you not use a for loop?

Comment: actually you are right! I don't know why I haven't think of a for loop... but it won't take too long to plot hundreds of spheres using a for loop? I will try anyway thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it in generic form.... You are almost there:

```
s = surf((x-cx)*r,(y-cy)*r,(z-cz)*r,'FaceAlpha',0.1);
```

Now just change `cx,cy,cz` with loops

Comment: yeah thank you I think a loop will work well! Don't know why I'm stucking here :)